# What are the rituals to be performed for a dead kitten at our house?

Tags: rituals, death, animals

A 3 days kitten died in our house. We tried to bring her to life but failed. What type of rituals should we do? Are there any rituals to distribute salt among neighbours and like that?

Comment: This is not a personal advice question. This is not asking help about personal issues. It is asking suggestions to cremate or to do rituals for a dead animal. This falls in the scope of our site. Also leaving it open in the review.